# IOS/Swift : make something work when the app launched

Tags: ios, swift

how to make any thing to work when the page did load but how?
like this number generator:

```
label.text = String(arc4random_uniform(9999))
```

I tried to put it under the fun didLoad - didAppear"nah not workink and give me an error" ...? How to make this work?

2/how to make the any button go to the next page if the answer was true, if not so still don't go any where?

Comment: Post your real not-working code and show which exactly part of it does not work for you.

Comment: ops i think i solved the problem :) sorry ,, can you help me with the second question please

Comment: delete the question then :)

Comment: how can i edit the question my friend

Comment: I guess you need more reputation points for edit. Simply delete this question and post new one

Comment: i think i can't do that too ,, my really i want to let any button go to the next page if the method of "if" was true . how ?

Answer (score 0):

You have mentioned in the comments that you've solved your first question so I'll answer your second question.

If you're using storyboards, the method that gets called when you go from one view controller to another is [`prepareForSegue`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/prepareForSegue:sender:). There is another method named [`shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier:sender:) that gets called just before the above method is called. This is where you should check for any conditions and determine whether the segue should really go through or if it should be halted.

Comment: ok how to use it please ? what i want is : when i push the button for example ,i want this button look for "if" and if its true "push" to the next page , and if its not so just "don't push" . i hope you got the idea <3